# Pinning zipcodes to Open Street Maps shapefile

Tags: sas, openstreetmap, shapefile

I am trying to pin a few zipcodes in my dataset to a map. I decided to use openstreet maps as I could download the states shapefile. I assumed that I could do something like this in my code "if zipcode=openzipcode then pin" (pseudocode)
But I can't figure out what the attribute is called in the shapefile, I thought maybe "postalcode"? But I am also seeing that maybe I would have to send the point to nominotim or openstreetmaps query online and download the image for each point, then layer the images to get all the points in one map. 
The problem is I cannot search for the points online for security reasons. I can only use a downloaded map with the information in it (such as zipcodes), I assumed the shapefile I downloaded contains the points but maybe I am wrong?

Is this possible from the shapefile?
Is there an online example with SAS? because I can't find any in regards to openstreetmap.
Here is where I downloaded the [shapefile](http://download.geofabrik.de/north-america/us/florida.html).

I have never used map visualizations and feel very lost. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: When you import the shapefile, using PROC GMAP, it creates a SAS dataset. You can browse the dataset and see what you need. SAS has the maps built in or available online http://support.sas.com/rnd/datavisualization/mapsonline/html/home.html. SASHELP has a zip code file that will map zip codes to lat/long. There's tutorials online, search lexjansen.com

Comment: http://robslink.com/SAS/democd57/aaaindex.htm Samples + code available here.

Comment: Thank you!!! You are so amazing!!! If you place your answer below and not as a comment I can mark it as best answer.

Comment: @Reeza another question. I am going through this [code](http://robslink.com/SAS/democd57/jordan_lake_paddling.sas) and I don't quite understand this part _%include '../data_vault/proxy.sas';
/*
I %include a file that sets the my_proxy macro variable.
You won't be able to use my proxy, therefore set your own
macro variable, which will be something like the following:

*/
/*%let my_proxy=http://yourproxy.com:80;*/ _

Comment: @Reeza: would that mean %let my_proxy=http://127.0.0.1.com:8080? Thanks